# 500 exception while connecting to live server using Volley in android

Tags: android, web-services, rest, android-volley

I'm trying to connect to live server using volley authentication and sending values through POST method. It worked well when connected to local server but I'm getting the below exception when connecting to live server.

> BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for "URL"

And server side error is below

> Error parsing media type 'application/json; charset=utf-8, application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' Expected separator ';' instead of ',' This is the error getting in server side

Here is my code

```
public void userLogin(){
    showDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);

    final String json = new Gson().toJson(arr);

    StringRequest jsonObjReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Const.URL_LOGIN,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    System.out.println("LOGIN Response :" + response);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
            System.out.println("NetworkResponse "+ networkResponse);
            if (networkResponse!= null && networkResponse.statusCode == 401) {
                Login.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        invalidemail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        inactiveaccount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });

            }
            error.printStackTrace();
            removeDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);
            toast_tv.setText("There is no Internet connection. Try again...!");
            toast.show();
        }
    }){

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() {
            try {
                return json == null ? null : json.getBytes("utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s",
                        json, "utf-8");
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();

            String credentials = String.format("%s:%s",Const.auth_username,Const.auth_password);
            String auth = "Basic "
                    + Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(),
                    Base64.NO_WRAP);
            headers.put("Authorization", auth);
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

            return headers ;
        }
    };

    jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20 * DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS, 0, 0));
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonObjReq);
}
```

On the server side Jersey is being used with Java.

Comment: Its probably error on the server side.

Comment: 500 is error status for internal server error.

Comment: But it is working in ios and the same server is used for both android and ios. @SripadRaj

Comment: or probably you must be sending wrong parameters to the server making it crash.

Comment: When I print the values before posting, it is correct @SripadRaj

Comment: My opinion is to check with your server side and check what is causing the server to crash.

Comment: Error parsing media type 'application/json; charset=utf-8, application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' Expected separator ';' instead of ','  This is the error getting in server side @SripadRaj

Comment: try changing your header to this `application/json; charset=utf-8; application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. You have missed a semi-colon after `charset=utf-8`. Maybe that is causing the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123909/discussion-between-nivedha-s-and-sripadraj).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed the issue.. Actually nothing wrong in code but the volley version which i used was deprecated. When **updating the volley library** it worked for me.